# Login with python module requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to log me in a website with requests, but all I have try don't work :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
s = requests.session()
url = 'https://www.ent-place.fr/CookieAuth.dll?GetLogon?curl=Z2F&reason=0&formdir=5'


def authenticate():
    headers = {'username': 'myuser', 'password': 'mypasss', '_Id': 'submit'}
    page = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(page.content)
    value = soup.form.find_all('input')[2]['value']
    headers.update({'value_name':value})
    auth = s.post(url, params=headers, cookies=page.cookies)

authenticate()
```

or :

```
import requests

payload = {
    'inUserName': 'user',
    'inUserPass': 'pass'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.ent-place.fr/CookieAuth.dll?GetLogon?curl=Z2F&reason=0&formdir=5', data=payload)
    print(p.text)
    print(p.status_code)
    r = s.get('A protected web page url')
    print(r.text)
```

When I try this with the .status_code, it return 200 but I want 401 or 403 for do a script like 'if login'...

Somebody know how to do ?

Comment: 200 is success and 400 is client error

Comment: I know but it can't be 200 with this login info : 'user' and 'pass' ?

Comment: Yes the page can still return 200 even if there is invalid login details. check the requests in your browser using a HTTP header inspector.

Comment: Ah ok but how I can know it is invalid login ?

Comment: inspect the content of the page, i.e. `r.text`

Comment: but i see nothing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can just try this.

Your login url is not correct, you can check the network requests in browser's developer tools.

```
import requests

payload = {
    'username': 'user',
    'password': 'pass'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.ent-place.fr/CookieAuth.dll?Logon', data=payload)
    print(p.text)
    print(p.status_code)
```

Comment: The url in your question just open the login web page, let you input username & password then click login button, then username & password will be passed to the login url. You can check this in browser's developer tools.

Comment: View the page's HTML source, and look for the form.

Comment: But I can't see if the login infos are correct or not

Comment: Somebody know how I can do for see if it's correct login infos or not ?

Answer (score 0):

These are the parameters your should be supplying.

```
curl:Z2F
flags:0
forcedownlevel:0
formdir:5
username:yourusername
password:yourpassword
SubmitCreds.x:57
SubmitCreds.y:23
SubmitCreds:Ouvrir une session
```

Comment: this parameters are just for this website or are universal ?

Comment: Just for this website, it depends on how the owners have designed it.